# Extracting Identity-H encoded text with iText

Tags: itext, extract

I am trying to extract text from a pdf file. The text is selectable in Acrobat. Acrobat lists ArialUnicodeMS font with type:TrueType (CID) and encoding:Identity-H.

Using a snippet

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filePath);
String content = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 1);
```

I am getting something back but it is unreadable when outputted to standard output or to a file (the output looks like blank characters). How can I extract Identity-H encoded text?

Answer (score 0):

It's a longshot but have you tried setting your pdf to version 1.2, identity-H encoding is double byte encoding of fonts, this is used mostly for Asian fonts and all Indesign generated pdf's.

If you don't have features in your pdf like i.e. gradients, transparancy you could try it (make a back-up of your pdf before you do, like I said before it's a long shot, just thinking out loud)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I cannot be changing my pdf in order to get it read. I switched to pdfbox which apparently has no problems.